# How to add static route in Virtual Guest to reach Host network?

Tags: linux-mint, ip, vmware, route

I have a Linux mint virtual machine running with public IP as 203.x.x.x with bridge mode Ethernet adapter whereas my physical machine IP Address is 145.17.x.x subnet.

To access my physical PC's subnet I have aliased one of the IP address from 145.17.x.x subnet. I can reach only the physical PC's own subnet as 145.17.10.X but I cannot reach other subnets as 145.17.11.X, 145.17.12.X, 152.X.X.X that all are accessible from my physical PC's network.

I want to reach my physical PC's all the subnets from my Virtual PC like 145.X.X.X, 152.X.X.X, 159.X.X.X.

What routes do I need to add in my Virtual Host?

Comment: Are you sure you set the right netmask for your 145.17.10 address?  If you gave it a /24 instead of a/16 or /8 you wouldn't be able to reach a lot of those addresses--and might actually have trouble with some stuff in the same /24 space.  Make sure your netmask in the guest matches the one on the host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the routing table of the 'Physical' PC and see how traffic to these networks are routed. If that host is only 'equipped' with a default route you need to use that address to add your static routes on the guest.

For example, the 'physical' host has only a static route of 145.17.1.1:

```
route add -net 145.17.0.0/16 gw 145.17.1.1
route add -net 152.0.0.0/8 gw 145.17.1.1
```

If the 'physical' host has multiple routes configured you need to use the appropriate addresses for each route.

To view the routing table you can use `netstat -rn`

Comment: Yes it worked. I set the route with 145.17.0.0/16 and it can reach all the subnets. Thanks for the help.